# Difference between "decoded input" and "input" in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

What is the difference between "decoded input" and "input" in the remix output? If these functions were to be called in an actual blockchain, would the "decoded input" be saved in a block, and thus visible to all? For example, in the attached figure, are the 0x01 and 0x04 values saved in a transaction. 'submitRange' is a public function. For context, I am wanting to keep this information private. [image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's technically no such thing as "private" information on a public blockchain everything is visible. If you want to conceal information you must encrypt it first.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function `submitRange(uint256 lower, uint256 upper)`.

Input is the raw field in the transaction that represents function and parameters that you want to execute.

Decoded input is the high level interpretation, remix will extract the parameters passed to the function.

As sated by foba everything in Ethereum is public and available to miners and nodes.